# How to make FragmentHighlighter to highlight an element with pure highlighter's color in openbim-components (IFCjs) + THREE.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, highlight, ifc

I using openbim-components (IFCjs) library alongside with THREE.js and face a problem that a tool for highlighting in openbim-components library (FragmentHighlighter) just adds a new mesh (with a material for highlighting - in my case it is a gray color) to the scene. Meaning that **the old mesh is still there**.
Apparently, this collision creates an effect of overlapping: both meshes are in the same place, but their materials are different. So the materials are mixing.
[If elements are white highlighting work as it must](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1pkv.gif)
[But if elements' meshes are not white the highlighting overlaps and mixes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDJto.gif)
I need to achieve a highlight color (pure gray as at the first image) to be when elements are not gray (as at the second image).
Thanks in advance!

I attempted to set:

```
material.polygonOffset = true
material.polygonOffsetFactor = 1
material.polygonOffsetUnits = 1
```

to the first mesh's material, but it didn't work
Any attempts to adjust `depthTest` (true for the highlighter's matertial and false for the element's one) failed, too

Comment: Just so I'm sure what your request is - the selected element should always have a grey coloured mesh?

Comment: FiddlingAway, yes,  the selected element should always have a grey coloured mesh